# Folded Map Effect on iOS

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am trying to add folded effect onto mapview similar to map in this image http://dribbble.com/system/users/11236/screenshots/311711/app-ui.png?1321121645. Tried to google for it but without luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that they are just overlaying an image with the folds/shadows/edges to give the effect. The actual map itself does not look like it is manipulated at all.